# how to set up a static ip for raspberi pi through the sd card

Tags: networking, ip, raspberry-pi

My school gave me a static IP address, sub/mask, DNS and alternate DNS in one of the outlets in my room.

**What I want:**

Set up through the SD card (windows explorer->sd->config something ip=)

Then I want to use putty to connect to it with the IP provided to me.

**What I don't want is**

To connect it to a monitor (I don't own one or a keyboard)

Can someone help me, I have no other way connecting to it.

Comment: There's no means to do that in the boot configuration. Instead change the IP address on your windows machine to be on the same subnet as the RPI, use putty to connect and change its static IP to the one you want (or to DHCP). However - questions like this should be asked at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: how can he find out the subnet of the RPI without a monitor nor a connection to it?

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a direct connection between your raspberry and computer via a cross-over ethernet cable ([wiki-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable)). If you are going for this solution you need to set up a DHCP-Server on your computer to give the raspberry an ip-address. If you done this you will be able to connect via ssh to you raspberry pi.

This isn't a trivial way to connect to your raspberry, i recommend you to get a screen and a keyboard. If this is not a option, i wish you good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a monitor to know the IP of Raspberry Pi.

**Step 1**: Connect it to ethernet.

**Step 2**: Find the IP of Raspberry Pi by a IP Scanner software or by accessing to the router (normally through address 192.168.1.1)

**Step 3**: Access to Raspberry Pi with the IP through Putty

**Step 4**: Set the static IP for Raspberry Pi with this [tutorial](http://www.modmypi.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address)